# Is there any way to shorten these lines

Tags: haskell

```
type Parser a = String -> Maybe (a, String)

parseChar :: Char -> Parser Char
parseChar _ "" = Nothing
parseChar ch (x:xs) | x == ch = Just (ch, xs)
                    | otherwise = Nothing

parseAnyChar :: String -> Parser Char
parseAnyChar "" _ = Nothing
parseAnyChar _ "" = Nothing
parseAnyChar (x:xs) str | isJust res = res
                        | otherwise = parseAnyChar xs str
                        where res = parseChar x str
```

I'm a beginner in haskell and I would like to know how can I use parseChar in parseAnyChar in a more "haskell way" than looping recursively. Using a map for example or anything else but I can't find.

Comment: You can make use of `Alternative` instance: `parseAnyChar (x:xs) str = parseChar x str <|> parseAnyChar xs str`, and thus use a `foldr` on that.

Comment: I have never seen Alternative nor foldr so I'm going to take a look. Thanks :)

Comment: Don't edit a solution into the question. If necessary, you can add an answer of your own.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For one thing, you can just use a standard function instead of manual recursion, to try `parseChar` on all the specified alternatives:

```
import Data.List (find)

parseAnyChar cs str = case find isJust ress of
    Just res -> res
    Nothing  -> Nothing
 where ress = [parseChar c str | c<-cs]
```

...or shorter

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
import Control.Monad (join)

parseAnyChar cs str = join . listToMaybe $ (`parseChar`str)<$>cs
```

A more efficient solution is to not attempt all the options in the first place, but instead use a [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Set.html) of options:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

parseOneCharOf :: Set.Set Char -> Parser Char
parseOneCharOf _ "" = Nothing
parseOneCharOf cs (x:xs)
   | x`Set.member`cs  = Just x
   | otherwise        = Nothing
```

...or shorter

```
import Control.Monad (guard)
parseOneCharOf cs (x:xs) = guard (x`Set.member`cs) >> Just x
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `maybeToList` solution? It looks like it returns a different type.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that won't work either -- it has the wrong type too wrt the OP's signatures. Perhaps you need `asum` instead, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**`Alternative`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) instance of `Maybe`:

```
import Control.Applicative((<|>))

parseAnyChar :: Foldable f => f Char -> Parser Char
parseAnyChar xs str = foldr ((<|>) . (`parseChar` str)) Nothing xs
```

This works since, `(<|>)` for `Maybe` is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1046):

> ```
> instance Alternative Maybe where
>     empty = Nothing
>     Nothing <|> r = r
>     l       <|> _ = l
> ```

So in case the left operand is `Nothing`, we pick the right one, if the left one is a `Just …`, we pick the first one.

We thus can rewrite the `parseAnyChar` to:

```
parseAnyChar :: String -> Parser Char
parseAnyChar "" _ = Nothing
parseAnyChar _ "" = Nothing
parseAnyChar (x:xs) str = parseChar x str <|> parseAnyChar xs str
```

We do not need a special case for the second parameter being `""` however, since this is already covered by the logic in `parseChar`. We thus can drop the second clause:

```
parseAnyChar :: String -> Parser Char
parseAnyChar [] _ = Nothing
parseAnyChar (x:xs) str = parseChar x str <|> parseAnyChar xs str
```

and now we can rewrite this to a `foldr` pattern.

This also makes it possible to use an `Foldable` as source of characters.

If the number of items is however large, you might want to use a more efficient data structure, like [@leftroundabout suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64136107/67579).

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I don't think a beginner can easily understand it.